# Seasoning steak with broiler salt

Tags: salt, steak, barbecue, seasoning, kosher-salt

I’ve always wanted to season a steak by just applying kosher salt before putting it in the bbq grill.

A few months I tried using this technique (https://www.thespruceeats.com/seasoning-your-steak-keep-it-simple-995234) and using this *broiler salt* (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUtdW.jpg ) on a thick ribeye steak (about 1.5”). Needless to say, it was so salty that I couldn’t eat it.

I want to do the same thing today, but with a thin tbone steak (about 0.5” thick).

My question: how do I season this steak with just the broiler salt in the picture?

Answer (score 3):

Salt is just ....salt....no matter how it is labeled (assuming it is not a spice mix, with other ingredients).  It might be more finely or coarsely ground, but....it's all the same.  Just use less...a sprinkle on each side.  You can always add more when you serve if you desire.

Comment: I understand that, but why are there so many cooking links saying that I should use lots of salt?

Comment: "Lots" is subjective.  It also depends on the size of the grind.  If you add "lots" of coarse salt, a bunch will fall off when it hits the grill....but..."lots" of fine salt might will stick more and perhaps be too salty.  Start with less.  Use the same salt consistently.  That way you get a feel for dosing.  Again...you can always add more.  It is almost impossible to undo too much salt.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf Salt pulls moisture towards the surface of the meat and helps with the maillard reaction, forming a nice "crust" that's delicious. It also allows moisture to escape, which reduces water content in the beef/chicken/fish, which intensifies the meat flavor. Salt also is known to enhance the flavors of whatever you are eating, since human taste-buds have been developed to crave saltiness, and therefore reward the brain with pleasure signals as you eat. Salting your meat before cooking is definitely a good thing, just don't overdue the salt, otherwise it'll just taste salty!